# Non computational approach to this equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, systems-of-equations, linear-programming

I was thinking about the following problem (*not homework*):

Let $a,b,c,d \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$

Find all four digit numbers $abcd$ where the two digit numbers
$$ \underline{(ab)}+\underline{(cd)}$$ sum to the two digit number $\underline{bc}$.

---

My approach:

Let
$$ N = 1000a + 100b + 10c + d$$
where $a,b,c,d \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$

For any given solution for $N$, we must have that
$$(10a+b) + (10c+d) = 10b+c$$
$$\therefore 10a - 9b + 9c + d = 0$$

It was at this point that I figured the problem could be taken no further by hand, and I used a programming language to iterate over all possible values to find where the equation holds. There were 55 solutions (*this is correct*).

My question is, could I have taken this problem any farther (*or have taken a different approach altogether*) **without** using a computer to find the solutions (*or manually attempting each combination*)?

Here are the solutions, from which you can derive several patterns/constraints:

> 0000 0109 0110 0219 0220 0329 0330 0439 0440 0549 0550 0659 0660 0769 0770 0879 0880 0989 0990
>
> 1208 1318 1428 1538 1648 1758 1868 1978
>
> 2307 2417 2527 2637 2747 2857 2967
>
> 3406 3516 3626 3736 3846 3956
>
> 4505 4615 4725 4835 4945
>
> 5604 5714 5824 5934
>
> 6703 6813 6923
>
> 7802 7912
>
> 8901

Comment: Do you mean $\underline{ad} + \underline{cb} = \underline{bc}$? otherwise your last equation is wrong.

Comment: @kennytm Aggh miswrote, thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the formula you already got
$$
10 a + d = 9 (b - c)
$$
you obtain that $0 \le 9 (b - c) \le 99$, and thus $0 \le b - c \le 11$. Clearly the values of $b, c$ determine the values of $a, d$.

So there is $1$ solution when $b = 0$ ($c$ can only be $0$), there are $2$ solutions when $b = 1$ ($c$ can be $0, 1$), etc, $10$ solutions when $b = 9$ ($c$ can be $0, 1, \dots , 9$).

All in all $1 + 2 + \dots + 10 = 55$ solutions indeed.

Comment: This is awesome, I knew I was almost there with no Python.  Thanks!

Comment: @JimSimmons, you're welcome!